# C# Unusual xml parsing

Tags: c#, xml

I have to parse one xml file to another, strictly defined one. The original file looks something like this:

```
<Data>
    <Client>
        <id>ID1</id>
        <Details>
            <detail1>1</detail1>
            <detail2>2</detail2>
        </Details>
        <Details>
            <detail1>3</detail1>
            <detail2>4</detail2>
        </Details>
    </Client>
    <Client>
        <id>ID2</id>
        <Details>
            <detail1>1</detail1>
            <detail2>2</detail2>
        </Details>
    </Client>
    <Client>
        <id>ID3</id>
        <Details>
            <detail1>1</detail1>
            <detail2>2</detail2>
        </Details>
    </Client>
</Data>
```

Basically all I need to do is to rewrite the file with different node names and parse some data within nodes, the structure itself remains the same.
Right now I have:

```
var ClientNodes = xml.SelectNodes("//Client");
for (int i = 0; i < ClientNodes.Count; i++)
{
    // this iterates through all Client nodes

    var DetailsNodes = xml.SelectNodes("//Details");
    for (int j = 0; j < DetailsNodes.Count; j++)
    {
        // this iterates through ALL "//Details" nodes and that's the problem

    }

}
```

If I just loop through the Details node as seen above, I would recieve something like:

```
<Client>
    <id>ID1</id>
    <Details>
        <detail1>1</detail1>
        <detail2>2</detail2>
    </Details>
    <Details>
        <detail1>3</detail1>
        <detail2>4</detail2>
    </Details>
    <Details>
        <detail1>1</detail1>
        <detail2>2</detail2>
    </Details>
    <Details>
        <detail1>1</detail1>
        <detail2>2</detail2>
    </Details>
```

I have no clue how to approach this problem. The main issue is that some Client nodes can have 2 or more Details nodes.
The best solution (I think) would be finding a way to iterate through all nodes within a single Client node, but I have not idea if that's possible (and that's why I decided to write my problem here), plus the files I have to deal with have ~20 nodes within a single Details node.

Comment: Do you have XSD files for input and output?

Comment: Shouldn't `var DetailsNodes = xml.SelectNodes("//Details");` be more like `var DetailsNodes = ClientNodes.SelectNodes("//Details");` notice how I replaced `xml` with `ClientNodes`. Right now you are first selecting all `Client` nodes, then you loop through them. By with every loop, you are selecting *all* `Details` nodes by doing the `SelectNodes` on the entire `xml` object again.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis this doesn't seem to work. Both ```DetailsNodes``` and ```ClientNodes``` are ```XmlNodeList``` type and they don't have ```SelectNodes()``` method.

But that a nice point to start from, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would *strongly* recommend using LINQ to XML instead of XPath for this. (You *can* use XPath, certainly - but it's less readable IMO. You'd just need to use `ClientNodes[i].SelectNodes("Details")`.)

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(...);
foreach (var client in xml.Root.Elements("Client"))
{
    // Do whatever you need to here
    foreach (var detail in client.Elements("Details"))
    {
        // Do whatever you need to here
    }
}
```

LINQ to XML is a *wonderful* XML API, and well worth learning about...

Comment: Wow, is it really that simple? I need to check this, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

`//` at the start makes the search expression relative to the document root. You want to use `.//Details` instead - see [Context for XPath Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256199(v=vs.110).aspx)

> An expression that uses the double forward slash (//) indicates a
>   search that can include zero or more levels of hierarchy. When this
>   operator appears at the beginning of the pattern, the context is
>   relative to the root of the document. For example, the following expression refers to all  elements anywhere within the current document:
>
> ```
> //author
> ```
>
> The .// prefix indicates that the context starts at the level in the hierarchy indicated by the current context.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently done something very similar, and the best solution I found was the code below:

```
foreach (XmlElement element0 in xml.GetElementsByTagName("Client")
{
     // your code
    foreach (XmlElement element1 in client.GetElementsByTagName("Details")
    {
         // your code
    }
}
```

Basically what this code will do is to go through every node that has the name "Details" within a client, then it will move on to the next client and repeat the process.

Answer (score 0):

Let use this code

```
string s = "<Data><Client><id>ID1</id><Details><detail1>1</detail1><detail2>2</detail2></Details><Details><detail1>3</detail1><detail2>4</detail2></Details></Client><Client><id>ID2</id><Details><detail1>1</detail1><detail2>2</detail2></Details></Client><Client><id>ID3</id><Details><detail1>1</detail1><detail2>2</detail2></Details></Client></Data>";
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml(s);

//Store nodes in variables
XmlNodeList Client, Details;

//Get all clients
Client = xDoc.SelectNodes("/Data/Client");

foreach (XmlNode cn in Client)
{

    //Get all Details parents
    Details = cn.SelectNodes("Details");
    foreach (XmlNode dn in Details)
    {
        //Get all "sub" detail of parents, or details values
        foreach (XmlNode n in dn.ChildNodes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(n.InnerText);
        }
    }
}
```

The error you did was to always use a high level XML element